Electromagnetic reflection without velocity change
The Fresnel equations describe the reflection and transmission of electromagnetic waves between two media. The parameter in the equations is the impedance ratio, where the impedance is $Z=\mu/\epsilon$. If the materials are non-magnetic, then the reflection depends only on the ratio of velocities, $v=1/\sqrt{\mu_0 \epsilon}$.
In principal, we can have two media with equal velocities, and still have reflection. For this we need both a change in $\mu$ and in $\epsilon$, which i guess is uncommon.
Was this ever realized experimentally?

I do not know of any direct measurements for the case of constant $\sqrt{\epsilon\mu}$ but indirectly what you are asking is proven by every ferrite based isolator/circulator designed to work between 900MHz and 100GHz. One obvious problem with such direct measurement is the lack of such material, that is one with low permittivity and high permeability. Unfortunately, RF or optical quality materials, ones that have low loss, also have high permittivity and low permeability, and but if there was one the other way around it would bring a multi-billion $$ revolution to the industry ...

While not the same as a real experiment, you may be interested to see a simulation of this scenario. I simulated this using my own FDTD solver.
The environment consists of two regions, whose interface is marked by the diagonal black line. The top left region has relative permeability 5, and relative permittivity 1. The bottom right region has them reversed, such that there is no velocity change across the boundary.
As a wave source, there are 39 point sources which sinusoidally drive the x-component of the H field. There is a phase delay between them such that the collective sources act as a phased array. You can see how they act to emit a "beam" toward the interface between the two regions.
When the beam interacts with the interface, we can see that a large portion of the energy passes through. There is no change in beam angle or wavelength, and so there cannot have been any velocity change (as expected). And yet, we can simultaneously see a reflected beam of lower intensity leaving to the right.

